# Error while Configuring a Software

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, malloc, configure

I get the following error while trying to configure a software :

```
checking for vector... yes
checking for malloc in -ljemalloc... no
configure: error: Need jemalloc
```

The solutions on the web haven't worked. I tried installing the jemalloc-devel package, jemalloc, libjemalloc package but they won't install.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libjemalloc
```

Installing libjemalloc1 didn't help. I still get the same error.

```
checking for vector... yes
checking for malloc in -ljemalloc... no
configure: error: Need jemalloc
```

Machine is Ubuntu 15.04, with gcc 4.9.2 . Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried installing the `libjemalloc` package

Comment: Do you get any feedback regarding *why* the jemalloc-devep package won't install?

Comment: why the downvotes when I said I tried the solutions ??? Don't downvote like this.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, I put it . plz see the edit. thx.

Comment: @Sim yes, i had tried that.

Comment: Saying you "tried the solutions" is useless if you don't say specifically *what* you tried : which package, which commands, on which system, and the exact error.

Comment: @Leiaz okay, i edited, sill people are not removing the downvotes, i would be banned to ask question next time.

Comment: Have you enabled the "universe" repo and `apt-get update`d?

Comment: Can you tell us which program/library you are trying to compile?

Comment: @molbdnilo I didn't apt-get update after enabling the universe repo, trying it again: (sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe) + apt-get update

Comment: @molbdnilo No, it didn;t work I still get checking for vector... yes
checking for malloc in -ljemalloc... no
configure: error: Need jemalloc

Comment: @SimonKraemer I am trying to install: https://github.com/keithw/remy

Comment: The package is still called `libjemalloc1` (Please notice the **1** at the end). You might also want to install `libjemalloc-dev`.

Comment: @SimonKraemer THanks Simon, this worked :). Thx a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The package **[jemalloc](http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/)** is missing form your system.

Comment: I tried that, of course. I get:  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libjemalloc

Comment: Try `libjemalloc1`. http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libjemalloc1
And enable the universe repo

Comment: @SimonKraemer I installed that and I still get the same error: checking for vector... yes
checking for malloc in -ljemalloc... no
configure: error: Need jemalloc

Comment: @PartidodelPartido I answered your question regarding this error  **E: Unable to locate package libjemalloc** but your update **I tried installing the jemalloc-devel package, jemalloc, libjemalloc package but they won't install.** is a different question

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAljehani No I had written that in the beginning also. I just didn't put the error message. Sorry for clumisness but I had tried those solutions..

Comment: @PartidodelPartido You did not mention what OS you're running. anyway try to install **jemalloc** and **jemalloc-devel**  from your distro package manager.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAljehani Ubuntu 15.04, with gcc 4.9.2, I am trying from package manager